# How to query LDAP via port 636 from powershell?

Tags: active-directory, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, ldap

I use adsi to connect to AD and measure the latency of the connection. For same query when i replace server with server:636 , it fails. What is the easiest way to do a ldap "find" through 636 port?

Comment: Are you sure your domain controller is actually listening on 636 over TLS? They don't by default unless you've added an appropriate certificate on the domain controller.

Comment: Definitely they do , thats why i am requesting help to monitor the latency of binds over 636.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same question as you did.  Here is a link that I found.  It worked perfectly.  I tested it against several of our Domain Controllers, and also against a vanity name i.e. ldaps.domain.com.  It worked as expected.

[Testing LDAP and LDAPS connectivity with PowerShell](https://evotec.xyz/testing-ldap-and-ldaps-connectivity-with-powershell/)

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault! Link only answers are not allowed. Please include relevant information to prevent issues with link-rot. Thank you.
https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer